# Javascript: setAttribute("onmouseover", "...function...") does not do anything

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I tried to write a user script for the greasemonkey add-on for firefox, that should change the behaviour of links on certain sites. If the script is running, the user should be able to open links by moving the mouse pointer over the link. If a new window opens, another one that has been opened before should be closed. 
That does not work and I do not have the slightest idea, why.

```
var numberOfAnchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a").length;
var window1;

for(var i=0; i<numberOfAnchors; i++){
    document.getElementsByTagName("a")[i]
        .setAttribute("onmouseover","followLink(this)");
}

function followLink(x){
    closeOldWindow();
    window1 = window.open(document.documentURI + x.getAttribute("href"));
}

function closeOldWindow(){
    window1.close();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to close `window1` before you even open a window, do a check before

```
function closeOldWindow(){
  if (window1)
    window1.close();
}
```

Comment: That does not change anything. I wrote an html-page for testing the script and it worked at first but only at that page. Then I installed greasemonkey and copied it into the user scripts and then did not even work on my page. (Not even with the Firefox JavaScript Environment)